# Styling side by side div blocks so that they stay in line

Tags: html, css

I have several divs side by side (which are inside a table).

I have styled these so that they are coloured blocks.

If all text inside the div fits on two lines, then it works fine. But If one overflows into another line, the whole div moves up a line. How do I stop this happening while keeping the same div width and making the text flow into the line below

I have used breaks in text to make sure the gap remains when text does fit on one line, but I will obviously need to remove this I assume.

```css
#main {
  margin-top:15vw;
  margin-left:5vw;
  margin-right:5vw;
  padding-right:3vw;
  padding-left:3vw;
  font-family:'Hind', sans-serif;
  color:black;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  font-size:2vw;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color:white;
}

#green{
  background-color: #f0f0df;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:1vw;
  height: 8vw;
  width: 12vw;
  line-height: 3vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
}
```

```html
<div id=main>

<div id=green>Title 1<br><b>Answer 1</b></div><div id=green>Title 2 (long title)<br><b>Answer 2</b></div><div id=green>Title 3<br><b>Answer 3</b></div><p id="rep">Additional text goes here. This text needs to be here but is not important and so does not need a box of its own. It is styled with italics and smaller font, and will probably be ignored.</p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: you said your div with in a table, but i don't see it in your code block.

Comment: it is a script sourced table, and I didn't think it necessary to add all of that code to be honest

Comment: if your blocks in a table then you can set the `td` as `<td valign="top">`

Comment: you can also use `vertical-align` as `ketan` give the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `vertical-align: top;` to `#green`

```css
#main {
  margin-top:15vw;
  margin-left:5vw;
  margin-right:5vw;
  padding-right:3vw;
  padding-left:3vw;
  font-family:'Hind', sans-serif;
  color:black;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  font-size:2vw;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color:white;
}

#green{
  background-color: #f0f0df;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:1vw;
  height: 8vw;
  width: 12vw;
  line-height: 3vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id=main>

<div id=green>Title 1<br><b>Answer 1</b></div><div id=green>Title 2 (long title)<br><b>Answer 2</b></div><div id=green>Title 3<br><b>Answer 3</b></div><p id="rep">Additional text goes here. This text needs to be here but is not important and so does not need a box of its own. It is styled with italics and smaller font, and will probably be ignored.</p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am sure I tried that, but maybe I had some other styling overriding it at the time. Works fine now

Comment: @J.Ayo glad to help. And don't forgot to mark it as answer.

Comment: I will... When it lets me in 11 seconds!